# post multidimensional array in dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two dropdown option with same name like following.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="freeoptions[]">
        <option value="[7][4]">Black</option>
        <option value="[7][5]">Blue</option>
        <option value="[7][3]">Red</option>
    </select>


    <select name="freeoptions[]">
        <option value="[9][11]">Small</option>
        <option value="[9][15]">Large</option>
        <option value="[9][13]">XL</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now when i am posting form, getting post data in array like,

```
Array
(
    [freeoptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => [7][4]
            [1] => [9][11]
        )
)
```

But I want this array something like

```
Array
        (
            [freeoptions] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                        [id] => [7]
                        [value] => [4]
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                        [id] => [9]
                        [value] => [11]
                )
            )
        )
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in a "value" attribute is sent as a literal string, regardless of it's content, so you can't post a value as an array out of the box.

You can always have both values in the same value attribute and split it in the back end.

Example in HTML:

```
<option value="7;4"></option>
```

Then do something like this in your back end:

```
$data = [];

// Loop all freeoptions params
foreach ($_POST['freeoptions'] as $opt) {
    // Split the value on or separator: ;
    $items = explode(';', $opt);

    if (count($items) != 2) {
        // We didn't get two values, let's ignore it and jump to the next iteration
        continue;
    }

    // Create our new structure
    $data[] = [
        'id'    => $items[0], // Before the ;
        'value' => $items[1], // After the ;
    ];
}
```

The `$data`-array should now contain the data structure you want.

If you want to keep using the `$_POST`-variable instead, just overwrite the original data after the foreach:

```
$_POST['freeoptions'] = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display result from database or display manually?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer